# Android ListView doesn't get populated in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

My custom adapter does not populate the ListView which is in a Fragment. It does not throw any exceptions and it doesn't get populated either.

> The ArrayList is NOT empty. I checked by printing them.

**My Fragment:**

```
    public class NewsfeedTabActivity extends Fragment {

    View rootView;
    private ArrayList<ActivityTable> activitiesList = new ArrayList<ActivityTable>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_newsfeed_tab, container, false);

            context = container.getContext();

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_newsfeed_tab, container, false);

            RefreshNewsFeed();
    }

    private void RefreshNewsFeed() {

            Log.e("CHECK", "HEY1");
            ListView newsreel = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_list); //the listview
            FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), activitiesList); //the adapter
            newsreel.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.e("CHECK", "HEY2");

            //The log successfully logs the HEY1 and HEY2
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

> In the above sample, HEY1 and HEY2 were successfully logged

**The adapter:**

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList<ActivityTable> actList = new ArrayList<ActivityTable>();

    public FeedAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<ActivityTable> actList) {

        activity = a;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.actList = actList;

        Log.d("CHECK", "WORKS1");
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return actList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d("CHECK", "WORKS2");

        View vi = convertView;
        ActivityTable act = actList.get(position);

        Log.d("CHECK", "WORKS3");

        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_single_text, null);
        }

        TextView caption = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.postcaption); // caption
        // Setting all values in listview
        caption.setText(act.getContent());

        return vi;
    }
}
```

In the adapter, only "WORKS1" gets logged in the constructor and the app doesn't log "WORKS2" and "WORKS3". I assume it gets stopped halfway? What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: Print actList size after ** Log.d("CHECK", "WORKS1");** and check. I'm sure it will be 0

Comment: It has 16 items mate. I just checked @CapDroid

Comment: I'm also wondering why there's a down vote for my question?

Comment: May be you shared half code, please share full code. I am not able to find out that code where you filling data into **activitiesList**

Comment: @CapDroid Just assume that it's full mate. It's a long code and I checked if the list is empty or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct instead of making Global root view object make the `ListView` as global object and check the list empty or not.

```
public class NewsfeedTabActivity extends Fragment {
    private ListView newsreel;
    private ArrayList<ActivityTable> activitiesList = new ArrayList<ActivityTable>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {           

           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_newsfeed_tab, container, false);
            newsreel = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_list); //the listview
           RefreshNewsFeed();
           return rootView;
    }

    private void RefreshNewsFeed() {

            Log.e("CHECK", "HEY1");

            FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), activitiesList); //the adapter
            newsreel.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.e("CHECK", "HEY2");

            //The log successfully logs the HEY1 and HEY2
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

To:

```
public ActivityTable getItem(int position) {
    return actList.get(position);
}
```

I generally change the `Object` return to the type that is being returned, in your case `ActivityTable`. This is also a good thing to do because you don't have to cast it later when you call `getItem`.

Comment: I had big hopes for this but no, mate. Still doesn't reach the end of the adapter :/